# How to fill an entire Bootstrap row with content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, row, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm trying to figure out how to get the entire width of a bootstrap row to be filled by 3 child span4s. It looks like theres still space left over after the final span4. Last time I checked 3 x 4 was 12, so what am I missing?

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="background-color:#eee; border: 1px solid #888;">
            <input name="srcCity" type="text" class="span4" placeholder="City">
            <select name="srcState" class="span4" data-country="US" data-state="CA"> </select>
            <input  name="srcZip" type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Zip">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ujq2vxqc/

Comment: I don't understand, you mean you're looking forward to eliminate the small gap on the left and right side ?

Comment: Maybe you're seeing something different. Mine looks like this: http://imgur.com/cCY3tbh
I want the content to fill the row, and there to not be space on the right side like there appears to be currently.

Answer (score 1):

I think you using wrong class, instead use `span4` (not exist in bootstrap.css file AFAIK) you can use `col-xx-4` with `xx` can be `xs`,`sm`,`md`,`lg` up to you.
Some thing like:

```
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="background-color:#eee; border: 1px solid #888;">
            <input name="srcCity" type="text" class="col-sm-4" placeholder="City">
            <select name="srcState" class="col-sm-4" data-country="US" data-state="CA"> </select>
            <input  name="srcZip" type="text" class="col-sm-4" placeholder="Zip">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I just tried col-sm-4 and col-lg-4 for all 3 elements, and the space on the right increases in both cases. The bootstrap css file I'm using defines span4 as: 

.span4{width:300px;}

Comment: After check again, i see you using Bootstrap.css v2.1.1 (which alot class is different ot not even exist anymore in Bootstrap.css 3.3.5 which i'm using) so my solution can't fix your problems, finding another solution but still suggest you using Bootstrap v3  if you not must using v2

Comment: I just updated your fiddle with my answer. change the width of your screen to show it takes the space up. https://jsfiddle.net/ujq2vxqc/22/

Answer (score 0):

As henry said you need to use `class="col-sm-4"`.
By default container has a padding of 15px, you would need to override this in your style sheet. th width of your screen relies on `.col-xs-X   .col-sm-X .col-md-X .col-lg-X` thew wider the viewport the larger column you want to use.

Also @media size is important in bootstrap. so lets say you have a 768px view the container in bootstrap is set to 750px. shown below.

```
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Original

```
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Make it somthing like this:

.container {
      padding-right: 2px;
      padding-left: 2px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }

```css
.container {
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.col-xs-1,
.col-sm-1,
.col-md-1,
.col-lg-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-sm-2,
.col-md-2,
.col-lg-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-sm-3,
.col-md-3,
.col-lg-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-sm-4,
.col-md-4,
.col-lg-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-sm-5,
.col-md-5,
.col-lg-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-sm-6,
.col-md-6,
.col-lg-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-sm-7,
.col-md-7,
.col-lg-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-sm-8,
.col-md-8,
.col-lg-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-sm-9,
.col-md-9,
.col-lg-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-sm-10,
.col-md-10,
.col-lg-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-sm-11,
.col-md-11,
.col-lg-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-12,
.col-md-12,
.col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background-color:#eee; border: 1px solid #888;">

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input name="srcCity" type="text" class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="City">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <select name="srcState" data-country="US" class="form-control col-lg-4" data-state="CA"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input name="srcZip" type="text" class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="Zip">

    </div>
  </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujq2vxqc/22/)